# system.Net.WebRequest - powershell - and 'The operation has timed out'

Tags: .net, powershell

I need to ask a lot of url`s with powershell and check status code

```
$Request = $null
$Request= [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Url)
$Request.Timeout = 100
$Request.AllowAutoRedirect = $true

 try {

       $Response = $Request.GetResponse()

     } catch [System.Net.WebException] {

       $someexception   = $_.Exception.Message 
     }

     $http_status      =  [int]$res.StatusCode

    if ([int]$Response.StatusCode.value__ -ne 200) #если не 200 - алерт
    {
        $state       = 'ERROR'


    }
        else
    {
        $state = 'OK' 


    }

$Request.Close
```

Any way i am trying to use it on server - its ok via manual test, but if i run a lot of scripts (in M$ SCOM for monitoring)  - SOME of them will fail with The operation has timed out

If i will check problem url - it is ok

Why it can time out in case lot of scripts in one time?how to debug it? Its is even http 200 from server logs ..

Answer (score 4):

`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit = 1024` before the request creation solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[The timeout property that you're setting to `100` is in milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

That's pretty short. Might want to set it to a few seconds.

It happens because the server side took longer than that amount of time to actually send the data. It may have sent a 200 response but the entire request did not complete in the time allotted. Definitely possible if you're sending a lot of requests at once.

Comment: Problem is not with timeout. Even with 10k timeout about 50% of 40 urls got time out with no season. Servers i am asking are very fast. Can it be some powershell / .net limitation ?

Comment: Also, urls are flapping over a time. Its ok and after 3 minutes - timed out..then ok again...etc... Look like some limitations ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no limitation in the .net classes. It sounds like a server side issue. If you can't get any more logging out of the server, try using a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) between your request and the server to see exactly what's going on. My guess is that you'll see the server not responding though, and will have to continue the investigation from the server side.

Comment: Its a limitation. [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit = 1024 before request create solved problem

Comment: @IgorKuznetsov ah nice! Please post it as an answer.